# How Can I Retrieve Files from my ipad?

Tags: ipad, macos, data-synchronization

I'm not sure that this is the right place but I really need some help!!!I connected my ipad  with my laptop  and my brother  pressed sync with the library itunes , but my laptop has not the photos and all things that had my ipad so everything form the laptop passed through  the ipad and everything from the ipad deleted!!Basically, if anybody knows of a program to get back my files, you are a hero!!  I didnt make a safe copy so  I cant reload the photo or files! I've never encountered this sort of problem and I don't know of any programs that are legitimate that do this; so if you guys could tell me of one I could easily get a hold of (preferably free) then I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say, but it's gone... G.O.N.E.

Unless your PC/Mac has the files, its gone. Check to make sure you still have Contacts, Photos, Apps, Music, Videos on your iPad AND on your PC/Mac by going into the respective apps and by checking iTunes.

Also check to see if you have a backup of your iPad by following these steps:

1. Connect your device to the computer that has your backup.
2. Install the latest version of iTunes.
3. Choose File > Devices > Restore from Back up.

If it has the backup, well make sure that it hasn't got anything on it. If it does, sync that information over before restoring.

Good luck!